# replicate fancytikzposter style in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I'm was using `fancytikzposter` package for my work until yesterday where I ran into a problem with the plots. So, as per some cool advice in this exchange ([Problem with pgfplots in tikzposter environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309380/problem-with-pgfplots-in-tikzposter-environment)), I switched over to the `tikzposter` class.

Unfortunately, the visuals of `fancytikzposter` are so cool that I'm not able to replicate the same in `tikzposter` despite `tikzposter` being really easy to use.

To better explain my problem, I shall show some comparison as to where I find let down by `tikzposter`. The fonts aren't so cool in `tikzposter` compared to the `fancytikzposter` and the logo positioning seems to be on the top rather than the left. I'm really not an expert with modifying the sty files. So, it would be really nice of you guys if you could help me replicate the same `fancytikzposter` style in a `tikzposter` environment.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: For the font, try `\sffamily` right after `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear to me, and the image is really blurry.

Anyways, a few things that may or may not be helpful:

## Logo

I see no logo in your image, and the only thing that is immediately obviously center aligned instead of left aligned is the title of the blocks. That is easily remedied, by adding

```
\useblockstyle[titleleft]{Default}
```

to the preamble.

If by logo you're referring to something inserted by `\titlegraphic`, then you need to use `\settitle` to redefine the layout of the title as mentioned in the manual. One simple definition that places the `titlegraphic` on the same line as the title, but at the far right of the line, is

```
\makeatletter
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \sc \hfill \@title \hfill\llap{\@titlegraphic}\par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}
\makeatother
```

Depending on length of title size of logo, overlap may occur, but I won't do any more without more specific instructions of what you want to achieve.

## Fonts

I don't know what "cool" means in this case, though I see that the poster on the left uses sans serif fonts for titles at least. Unfortunately the `tikzposter` class is not very flexible when it comes to this, it has no features for easily switching font styles.  You can of course use `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}` but that is tedious. Another option is to set sans serif font family as default, by adding

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

to the preamble.

## A complete example with these changes

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Rays}
\useblockstyle[titleleft]{Default}
\title{Something or other}
\author{A Bloke}
\titlegraphic{\rule{2cm}{2cm}} % black square as logo

\makeatletter
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \sc \hfill \@title \hfill\llap{\@titlegraphic}\par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Title}{
\lipsum[1]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Torbjorn, sorry for the trouble. I wanted the logo on the same line as the title. Or more specifically, the logo lies right beneath the title and its also easily scalable in fancytikzposter. I really wonder why these changes were reverted in tikzposter. But thank you so much for all the help mate :)

Comment: @crypto Sorry what? The same line as the title is not the same as right beneath the title. And it's not a question of reverting anything I think. Two projects were merged, and the new defaults are probably a mix of those two. If you have feature requests or similar for the `tikzposter` class, add a ticket at https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues